# Where is the en_US_POSIX locale constant defined?

Tags: ios, posix, locale

To use an invariant NSLocale in iOS we create a locale object using the LocaleID "en_US_POSIX". Where is this string constant defined in the iOS Cocoa or Foundation libraries? Would like to stop defining it myself in apps

Comment: What constants are you referring to? There are no constants for any locale ids.

Comment: I don't believe this string literal is defined as a constant anywhere. If you don't like setting this locale yourself, you can use [`NSISO8601DateFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsiso8601dateformatter) (called `ISO8601DateFormatter` in Swift), and it uses this locale automatically without having to specify it.

Comment: @rmaddy referring to creating an NSLocale via Locale ID. To make the invariant locale you use a string "en_US_POSIX". Other languages and platforms have this concept as a first class citizen (ex .NET Culture.Invariant)

Comment: @Rob This isnt about date formatting - just in general. There are all kinds of reasons and APIs that need the iOS locale info and for invariant there seems to be no way to grab it other than create yourself an even then no const defined

Comment: @stonedauwg I know all about NSLocale and locale ids. I'm asking you what constants you are referring to. There are no constants for any locale ids in Swift or Objective-C. You pass a string, that's it. If you don't want to type "en_US_POSIX" more than once, create your own constant.